VLAN-tagged LXC containers have no network access on a VLAN aware bridge
I have a dedicated server with Hetzner running Proxmox (Debian). The host itself does have internet access, but I can't get network access within my VLAN-tagged LXC containers when I'm using a transparent VLAN aware setup. On the other hand, creating a dedicated Linux VLAN interface does work as shown below.
I have 2 public IP addresses on the same subnet, IP aliased on a single NIC. The gateway is also on the same subnet. And a private IP range for containers, which is supposed to NAT with the aliased IP.
Containers have internet access with this config, but it's not desired because I'd have to create a new VLAN interface for each new VLAN ID I want to use.
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s10 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
  address x.x.x.150/26
  gateway x.x.x.122
  bridge-ports enp0s10
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0
  bridge-vlan-aware yes
  bridge-vids 2-4094

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
  address x.x.x.176/26

auto vmbr0.2
iface vmbr0.2 inet static
  address 192.168.178.1/24
  post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.178.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.176
  post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.178.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.176
  post-up iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
  post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1

I thought that it'd be straightforward like this, but not only can't tagged reach the internet, they also can't ping other containers in the same VLAN:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s10 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
  address x.x.x.150/26
  gateway x.x.x.122
  bridge-ports enp0s10
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0
  bridge-vlan-aware yes
  bridge-vids 2-4094

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
  address x.x.x.176/26

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
  address 192.168.178.1/24
  bridge-ports none
  bridge-stp off
  bridge-fd 0
  bridge-vlan-aware yes
  bridge-vids 2-4094
  post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.178.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.176
  post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.178.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.176
  post-up iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
  post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1

How do I get it so that I just have to tag a VM/container with a VLAN ID without the need to create a dedicated vmbr.<id> device for each VLAN, and get internet access through NAT?
Please let me know if additional info is required in order to give an answer.
